# jQuery: find multiple element types having a certain attribute

Tags: jquery

I currently have the following code:

```
$('input[data-geo], select[data-geo]').doSomething()
```

Ideally I'd like to only declare the `[data-geo]` attribute once. Not sure if this is possible, but something along the lines of:

```
$('(input, select)[data-geo]')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
​$('[data-geo]')​​​.​filter(':input')​
```

Tested successfully on this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cHJ6S/

For details see the following page on the jQuery web site:
http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Comment: It never occurred to me to use the `:input` pseudo-selector. `$(':input[data-geo]')` is absolutely perfect, no need for `filter`.

Comment: Yep, performance-wise it is suggested to first use a pure CSS selector, then use the jQuery filter extension: "To achieve the best performance when using :input to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":input").
" http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Comment: How so? I figured using `filter` means extra objects are first fetched?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) for such cases

```
$('input, select').filter('[data-geo]').doSomething()
```

This will select only the `input` and `select` elements that have the `[data-geo]` atribute..

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
$('[data-geo]').doSmth();
```

However, that means you are calling doSmth() on every element that has this attribute, not only `select` and `input`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to avoid. It's nothing important, just code-golf really.